Unable to execute Google Classroom API script due to possible threat detection
I work in the ICT department of a university. At the beginning of each semester, I need to create Google Classroom courses and enroll members based on the university's course data. I have been using a GAS program that utilizes the Google Classroom API to handle this task.
While the execution time limit for GAS is 30 minutes for Google Workspace for Education licenses, I have implemented a mechanism using script properties and triggers to allow the script to continue running for longer than 30 minutes due to the large number of courses.
Reference site: https://qiita.com/s_maeda_fukui/items/d194c6408803229fe1b9
Since the beginning of July 2024, the script has been terminating prematurely more frequently, and as of July 10th, it has completely stopped working.
GAS results
I have tried the following, but none of them have worked, and I am concerned that Google may have mistakenly flagged my program as malicious:

Executing the script from a different account
Copying the entire source code into a new GAS file and executing it
Executing a program for affiliated schools with slightly different source code

I have contacted the Google Workspace support desk, but they informed me that this is beyond their scope and directed me to a Stack Overflow post.
I would greatly appreciate your assistance in this matter.

It's unclear the purpose of the link and why it was labeled as a reference. Log messages should be added as text instead of images and should be in English. To get the messages in English, temporarily change your account language to English and run the script again.

Try to create a [mcve] and add it to the question.
